# Does kerosene get ignited by a spark plug?

Tags: engine-design, engines, liquid-fuel, ignition

Are spark plugs used in kero-LOx engine(say J1 engines)? If so, then there are two major issues when using spark plug to ignite kerosene.

1. Wetting of the spark plug causes spark to be smaller and the energy might be less. Sparks tend to be larger when used in gas media. Wetting of the electrode reduces spark size.
2. Due to the above, the temperature achieved might be less and hence kerosene might not be vaporised completely before reaching flash point.

How are these issues overcome?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Check Launcher space, a new startup from NY. They are using spark plug based ignition for kerosene! https://mobile.twitter.com/launcherspace/status/933101686700179457

Comment: I don’t know how they are making it happen!

Comment: What do you do with the spark plug after a successful ignition? I should not melt and burn through the combustion chamber wall. If the wall needs liquid cooling, the spark plug would need it too. The spark plug should not disturb the cooling of the surrounding wall.

Comment: @Uwe what if the stabilised flame front is after the spark plug? There will be significantly less heat flux at the spark plug

Comment: Is a spark plug before the stabilised flame front able to ignite the mixture of LOX and kerosene very close to the injection?

Comment: @Uwe I think it can. Thought of consulting before getting my hand dirty and testing.

Comment: If the arc of the spark plug is totally within a drop of kerosene no ignition takes place. The same is true for a drop of LOX. Only when the arc is within a gaseous mixture of kerosene and oxygen ignition will happen, if the mixture has neither too much or too less kerosene as well as oxygen.

Comment: Atomised kerosene in oxygen too might be difficult to ignite?

Comment: @karthikeyan I think there are some interesting questions and/or issues here. If you rewrote this question it could be reopened, but the better way would be to ask a new one. If you gave a specific example (link and possibly image as well) of a company, product, or research *within the question itself* (rather than in a comment) and asked something like "What exactly are they doing here?" or better yet "What would be the technical challenges to getting this to work?" there's a better chance for the question to stay open.

Comment: @uhoh as you suggested. I will gather my materials and get back soon. Thanks

Comment: @uhoh as you suggested - https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30668/511. Hope to figure this out!

Comment: @karthikeyan that looks great, thanks for the ping! I did a bit of edit, you are welcome to rollback the changes or edit further.

Comment: @uhoh okay! Got it.

Answer (score 4):

Spark igniters are commonly used for *hydrogen*-fueled engines, but chemical igniters are preferred for kerosene engines, largely because of the concerns you mention.

There's more detail [in this Q & A](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/why-is-tea-teb-chemical-ignition-used-instead-of-spark-ignition).

Comment: ah! Even I had commented! But still I a, seeing a lot of spark plug IC engine designs and precombustion chamber design. Wonder if larger voltage could kick in a kerosene spark ignition?

Comment: I don't think ICE engine design is generally comparable to rocket engine design even if the fuel remains the same, due to the rather huge volume/flow differences. They would seem to exacerbate the wetting concerns pointed out in the question.

Comment: @russell please do check this https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30668/511. Put up a new question based on @uhoh’s suggestion.