# How to overcome the challenge of igniting kerosene using spark plugs?

Tags: engine-design, liquid-fuel, engines, ignition

Discussions in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/why-is-tea-teb-chemical-ignition-used-instead-of-spark-ignition) and its answer, concerning the use of spark plug ignition for Kero/GOx system outlines the energy limitations of spark plugs to ignite the mixture.

But [Ignition Transient of Supercritical Oxygen/Kerosene Combustion System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ba8e/fe1dc7b992603940402db9f16a30ea867838.pdf) (Kim, Lee and Koo 2015, 25th ICDERS) clearly show that the ignition of kerosene/GOx using spark plug is possible. Also, Launcherspace, a startup from NY too make use of [spark plug for their ignition system](https://twitter.com/launcherspace/status/933101686700179457).

How are these systems able to overcome the energy requirements issue?

Comment: I guess the question is how do you get supercritical oxygen in the first place (where comes the heat?)? Also if ignition somehow takes longer, will you freeze the kerosene nozzle or coat the chamber with solid kerosene?

Comment: @user3528438 please refer to the paper. The abstract clearly mentions about how subcritically injected propellant becomes supercritical after combustion